# What is the difference: "would" vs "will"

Tags: will-would

Would you please to explain the differences?

> For example, this **would** be the exception to throw if the caller
>   attempted to use some object before it had been properly initialized.
>
> For example, this **will** be the exception to throw if the caller
>   attempted to use some object before it had been properly initialized.

Comment: Marked as duplicate... then why the hell did it show up on the StackExchange's home landing page?

Answer (score 0):

**Would** is conditional and **will** is not. In the usage listed in your example, I don't see any practical difference that a listener or reader might register. I think that the first sentence is more correct, because **if** indicates the condition under which that particular exception is to be thrown. If the word **if** were replaced with the word **when**, I would favor the second sentence. You will not be misunderstood or thought to be using English oddly with either sentence.

**Would** also has some common, colloquial uses that are not conditional in modern English (at least in the United States version of it), but in my experience these are generally verbal hedging. For example, I initially typed "I would say that the first sentence is more correct...", but that is confusing given this specific question and I can't think of a single grammar-based argument for why that's an acceptable construction.

Answer (score -1):

The uses of *will* and *would* are distinguished succinctly in [When should I use would / would have / will / will have?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have).

In the context of your example, *would* is used when you are describing a condition - something which *would* happen *if* something else happened first. *Will* is used when you are stating an intention or predicting the future - ie when the *condition* has already happened.

In your example there is a condition, so *would* is correct : "If the caller attempted to use some object, then ... would be the result."

However, I think there may be bigger problems with your sentence than the choice between *would* and *will*. The meaning of the sentence is far from clear. Perhaps the context would provide enough explanation. Otherwise, your concern about which word is correct is misplaced. Clear communication is much more important than using correct grammar.

In common practice, *would* and *will* are used interchangeably. English as a first language is not taught as thoroughly as when it is a second language. Considerable laxity is tolerated, especially in spoken English.

Comment: Using _would_ to explain the usage of the word _would_ would cause confusion, wouldn't it? In any case, the two verb forms are not used interchangeably in common practice. What is "common practice?"

Comment: @P.E.Dant : It might cause confusion, but the idea is to emphasize the form "X would happen if Y happened 1st." How can you say that the two forms are not used interchangeably "in common practice" if you do not know what "common practice" means? What I mean by it is common usage by ordinary native English speakers, rather than proponents of "correct" usage such as English language teachers.

Comment: Telling the quærent: _"Would" is used when you are describing a condition, something which would happen..._ doesn't advance the quærent's understanding, it seems to me. Your discussion of conditionality is apt, but I don't think a statement like _In common practice, would and will are used interchangeably_ is supportable. Examples: "How will you like your eggs?" "When would that train arrive?" &c. &c.

Comment: @sammy Just as a note on the sentence meaning in the OP's example, the terms are common in computer programming (specifically, object oriented programming). The sentence is clear but jargon-laden.

Comment: @Upper_Case Good point. In the OP's sentence, neither _would_ nor _will_ are even appropriate: _this **is** the exception to throw..._

Comment: @Upper_Case : Ah, thanks. Now it makes some sense. I did say that the context might explain the meaning.

Comment: @P.E.Dant : I don't understand your point about my statement being "insupportable" - your 2 examples look very natural both ways (will/would interchanged) and typical of reported speech in classic literature.

Comment: Posed to a station agent, the question "When would that train arrive?" might be met with puzzlement. Similarly, no waiter in my experience has asked: "How will you like your eggs?" The verbs forms have distinct meanings and usages. They _can_ be used interchangeably in some circumstances, but to tell a student of English that they **are interchangeable in common practice** does a disservice to the student. They aren't. (By the way, I don't know what period you connote by "classic literature," but the distinction between the two forms was even _more_ pronounced in the past.)

Comment: I doubt "When would that train arrive?" would be misunderstood. Only a pedant would pretend to do so. A waiter might not ask "How will you like your eggs?" but an upper class mother might ask it of a child. Telling a student how language is *actually* used by native speakers is not a disservice. Reported speech in literature follows idiosyncratic use among particular social groups, not *Queens English*. Natural speech is rarely well thought out like the written word. It is frequently ungrammatical. This is the difference between what *should* happen and what *actually does* happen.

Comment: That a ticket agent might _understand_ a question such as _When would that train arrive?_ does not support the contention that _will and would are used interchangeably in common practice._ In common practice, _would_ is used to refer to imaginary situations in the future. That's what makes it useful and what has kept it in our lexicon long after its original sense as the preterite of _willan_ faded.